# How bind data in vue.js when my key consists dash (-) in JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

My JSON data looks like:

```
{
    "color-1": "#8888",
    "color-2": "#000"
}
```

How can I bind this variable with style tag for vue component?
I am trying to use it in the following way, but its not working.

```
<div v-bind:style="{ color: data['color-1'] }"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generally access your component's `data` properties in the template by directly referring to them, without prefixing `this.` or `data.`. In your case, that's a problem, because it prevents you from using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

You have two solutions:

Solution 1: Don't put your JSON data directly in the component `data`, wrap it in an object (e.g. `colors`). This way, using `colors['color-1']` in the template will work.

Solution 2: Leave your data as is and write a simple method for getting properties in your component, then call it from the template. Something like:

```
methods: {
  getProperty: function (name) {
    return this[name];
  }
}
```

And then in the template:

```
<div v-bind:style="{ color: getProperty('color-1') }"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access all data properties via $data:

```
{ "color-1": $data["color-1"] }
```

Comment: This is actually much cleaner than the expected answer

Answer (score 1):

You can have hyphen-separated properties as strings.

```
<div v-bind:style='{ "color-1": data["color-1"] }'></div>
```

[Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue. Here's how to fix it:

```
<div v-bind:style="{ color: this['color-1'] }"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After finding some more details into similar problem, here is what I found [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3283#issuecomment-268455540)

Since `v-bind` expects a javascript expression, you can't use `-` in identifiers. If you really want to use `-`, you can use `v-bind:src="this['image-src']"` because `this` is accessible in templates.

Hope it helps!